# Is there any way to change WKPickerItem title's font size

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

Is there any way to change WKPickerItem title's font size.How to change it's title's font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it was of WKInterfaceLabel class type you could import UIKit, sub-classify it and in the init put something like:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0 weight:UIFontWeightUltraLight];
    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Ultra Light Label" attributes:attrsDictionary];
    [self.title setAttributedText:attrString];
```

But since the title is a NSString, and Watch 0S 2.0 is currently in beta, there is no way to change the WKPickerItem title's font size.

Comment: thanks for your reply,  however it not works, no function "setAttributedText" for NSString type.